# PHP - How can I display time correctly?

Tags: php, sql, database, db2

I am using PHP to query an AS400 DB2 database. The time(ADACTM) is saved in the table like;
[image: ADACTM field in DB2 Table]

I need to convert this to a human-readable format like 9:46:23.

I am currently doing this in PHP;

```
$adactm = str_split($fin2['ADACTM']);
$adactm = "$adactm[0]$adactm[1]:$adactm[2]$adactm[3]:$adactm[4]$adactm[5]";
```

The problem is, when the time doesn't have a 2-digit hour, PHP thinks array position 0 is actually position 1. So the time shows like;

```
94:62:3
```

If anyone has a way to fix this, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) the string before you split it:

```
$rawtime = '94623';
$padded = str_pad($rawtime, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); // 094623
```

Then split/mangle as before

Comment: Nice solution... but than you will get 09:46:23 not 9:46:23

Comment: yours works too. alternatively: split the string. count elements, push a '0' if necessary.

Comment: Thanks to both of you guys! I don't mind having the leading zero display, so I like this option because it's short. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Additionally you could put the padded number into a `DateTime::createFromFormat` call, so you'll get a [DateTime object](http://php.net/datetime) that you can format/manipulate as desired: `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('His', str_pad($rawtime, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT));`. Then you can do `echo $date->format('H:i:s');` or however you want to output it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, no better idea than this:

```
$adactm = str_split($fin2['ADACTM']);

if (count($adactm) == 5) {
    $adactm = "$adactm[0]:$adactm[1]$adactm[2]:$adactm[3]$adactm[4]";
} else {
    $adactm = "$adactm[0]$adactm[1]:$adactm[2]$adactm[3]:$adactm[4]$adactm[5]";
}
```